# conditional inside nested object in dustjs

Tags: dust.js

I have following allStudents object in dustjs file.I want to use conditional for name inside course(i.e. if(course.name == 'something'){//show something} else {//show something else}).I tried using eq but to no avail.How do I use eq for conditional inside nested object?

```
    [{
            name: 'john',
            course: [{
                name: 'history',
                course_id:2
            }, {
                name: 'philosophy',
                course_id:2
            }]
        }, {
            name: 'harry',
            course: [{
                name: 'science',
                course_id:3
            }, {
                name: 'history',
                course_id:3
            }]
        }]
```

This is how I am traversing the object.

```
        {#allStudents}
            {.name}
            {#.}
              {#course}
                {#.}
                    //here use conditional for name.
                {/.}
              {/course} 
              <br />
            {/.}
        {/allStudents}
```

Answer (score 2):

That would be a use for a logic helper. BTW `{#.}` does nothing for you in your example and isn't needed.

```
{#course}
  {@select key=name}
    {@eq value="science"}Blinded!{/eq}
    {@eq value="history"}Doomed to Repeat{/eq}
  {/select}
{/course}
```